# How to make an IMG stick to bottom of a div

Tags: html, css, position

I saw many posts and question asked on this issue but none was useful for me so i ask another one. I have a `div` that has some text in it and then an `img`, i have several of these `divs` in a row and when i open the page on different resolutions the texts sometimes expand to two rows instead of one, so the pictures are not on the same level. because of that i want to make the OMG stick to the bottom of the `div` so when the text expands they will still be on same level.
any suggestions?

code:

```
<div id="put_entry" class="main_banner">
    <h1>
        <center>
            <a href="published.php">published</a>
        </center>
    </h1>
    <center>i published those items<br /><center>
    <center>
        <img src="search_torent.png" id="index_banner" onclick="document.location='published.php';return false;"/>
    </center>
</div>
```

css:

```
.main_banner{
    margin-left: 15px;
    direction: rtl;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #D1E3F3;    
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 273px;
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
}

.main_banner img{
        cursor: pointer;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EFPt7/

```
.main_banner{
    margin-left: 15px;
    direction: rtl;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #D1E3F3; 
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 273px;
    width: 270px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.main_banner img{
    cursor: pointer; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: hello and thank you for your answer, in my code when i edited the css the IMG ran out of the DIV... any idea whhy?

Comment: you need to make the div `position: relative;` As I made there

Answer (score 0):

try `position:absolute` and then set the `width`, `height` and `margin`.

Answer (score 0):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EFPt7/15/

I suggest you should add new div for published item and then new row for img. Adding some code for css of new div like this for fixed min height of you publish and then new row for image. Anyway you can used align in div class main_banner.

---html---

```
<div id="put_entry" class="main_banner" align="center">
    <div>
    <h1><a href="published.php">published</a></h1>
        i published those items
        <br/>
    </div>
    <img src="https://www.google.co.th/images/srpr/logo4w.png" 
    id="index_banner" 
    onclick="document.location='published.php';return false;"  
    width="270px"/>
</div>
```

--- css ---

```
.main_banner{
     margin-left:15px;
     direction:rtl;
     border-radius:10px;
     background:#D1E3F3; 
     border:1px solid #707070;
     margin-top:10px;
     margin-bottom:10px;
     padding:10px;
     width:270px;
     float:left;
}

.main_banner img{
     cursor:pointer; 
}

.main_banner div{
     min-height:273px;
}
```